# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in requests what is problem?

Tags: python, string, testing, python-requests

```py
import requests
funciona = "0"
nofunciona = "0"
url = 'http://testphp.vulnweb.com/userinfo.php'
values = {'uname': 'test', 'pass': 'test'}
r = requests.post(url, data=values)

if "John" in r.content:
   funciona = 1
else:
   nofunciona = 1

print(r.content)
print(funciona)
print(nofunciona)
```

```
Console: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    if "John" in r.content:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: `r.content` is a bytes object not a string. You can't look for a string `in` bytes. Try decoding the response: `if "John" in r.content.decode(r.encoding):` or `str(r.content)` or `r.text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `bytes` and `str` are two different types.

Bytes are written:
`my_bytes = b'somebytes'`

Strings are written:
`my_string = 'somestring'`

So `"John"` in your code is a `str` and `r.content` is of type `bytes`. You need the types to match for this boolean expression to work.

So either you need to say `b"John" in r.content` or `"John" in r.text` where `r.text` is the string version of the content decoded with the appropriate codec (like UTF-8, ASCII, etc.).